# Incorrect result of AsymptoticSum

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Trying in version 13 on Windows 10

```
ClearAll[n, x, a]; 
AsymptoticSum[Sin[n*x]/(n - a), {n, 1, Infinity}, {a, 1, 1}, 
Assumptions -> a > 0 && a < 1 && x >= 0 && x < 2*Pi] // FullSimplify
```

> `-(1/2) I E^(-I x) (Log[1 - E^(-I x)] -  E^(2 I x) Log[1 - E^(I x)] - (-1 + a) PolyLog[2, E^(-I x)] + (-1 + a) E^( 2 I x) PolyLog[2, E^(I x)])`

, I obtain an incorrect result since `a==1` should be a singularity as

```
Plot3D[Evaluate[Sum[Sin[n*x]/(n - a), {n, 1, Infinity}]], {a, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 2*Pi}, PlotRange -> {-10, 10}]
```

[image]

demonstrates. Compare with

```
Plot3D[-(1/2) I E^(-I x) (Log[1 - E^(-I x)] - 
E^(2 I x) Log[1 - E^(I x)] - (-1 + a) PolyLog[2, 
E^(-I x)] + (-1 + a) E^(2 I x) PolyLog[2, E^(I x)]), {a, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 2*Pi}]
```

[image]

Is there a workaround? It should be noticed that the result of

```
Sum[Sin[n*x]/(n - a), {n, 1, Infinity}, Assumptions -> a > 0 && a < 1 && x >= 0 && x < 2*Pi];
Normal[Series[%, {a, 1, 1},  Assumptions -> a > 0 && a < 1 && x >= 0 && x < 2*Pi]]
```

is identical with the result of `AsymptoticSum`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround:

```
as = Sin[x]/(1 - a) +  AsymptoticSum[Sin[n*x]/(n - a), {n, 2, Infinity}, {a, 1, 1},  Assumptions -> a > 0 && a < 1 && x >= 0 && x < 2*Pi] //  FullSimplify
```

> `-1/2 I E^(-I x) (Log[1 - E^(-I x)] - (-1 + a) PolyLog[2, E^(-I x)]) +  1/2 I E^(I x) (Log[1 - E^(I x)] - (-1 + a) PolyLog[2, E^(I x)]) -  Sin[x]/(-1 + a)`

Indeed,

```
as /. {a -> 0.9, x -> Pi/2}
```

> `9.67399 + 0. I`

and

```
Sum[Sin[n*x]/(n - a) /. {a -> 0.9, x -> Pi/2}, {n, 1, Infinity}]
```

> `9.67292`

The question about `AsymptoticSum[Sin[n*x]/(n - a), {n, 1, Infinity}, {a, 9, 1},  Assumptions -> a > 8 && a < 9 && x >= 0 && x < 2*Pi]` which results in correct, but useless `-(1/2) I E^(-I x) (-HurwitzLerchPhi[E^(-I x), 1, 1 - a] +  E^(2 I x) HurwitzLerchPhi[E^(I x), 1, 1 - a])` remains open.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the assumptions concerning `a > 0 && a < 1`

```
asy=AsymptoticSum[Sin[n*x]/(n - a), {n, 1, Infinity},  a -> 1 ,Assumptions -> x >= 0 && x < 2*Pi] // FullSimplify

(*1/2 I E^(-I x) (HurwitzLerchPhi[E^(-I x), 1, 1- a] - E^(2 I x) HurwitzLerchPhi[E^(I x), 1, 1 - a])*)

Plot3D[{asy, Sum[Sin[n*x]/(n - a), {n, 1,Infinity}]} // Evaluate, {a,0.9, 1.1}, {x,0, 2 Pi}, PlotRange -> {-50, 50} ]
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but `1/2 I E^(-I x) (HurwitzLerchPhi[E^(-I x), 1, 1- a] - E^(2 I x) HurwitzLerchPhi[E^(I x), 1, 1 - a])` depends on `a`. This is simply wrong.

Comment: Nothing wrong: You are looking for an asymptotic expansion `a->1` which has to depend  on `a`!

Comment: As  written in my answer at the bottom, this is correct, but useless. Mathematica returns an analytical expression for the sum, not its asymptotic $\frac {\sin x} {1-a},\, a\to 1$.

Comment: Why should analytical expression returned by Mathematica compared to an expected expression $\frac{\sin (x)}{1-a}$ be useless?  Both are asymptotic!  I'm out of this fruitless discussion, sorry for trying to give you a helpful answer!

Comment: As written in the documentation to `HurwitzLerchPhi` "The Hurwitz\[Dash]Lerch transcendent is defined as an analytic continuation of $\sum_{k=0}^\infty z^k(k+a)^{-s}$" i.e. this sum itself, whereas $\frac {\sin x} {1-a}$ is a closed -form expression. Hope you understand the difference.